# Partition by rearranges table on each query run

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below query always rearranges my table (2021-01-01 not followed by 2021-01-02 but any other random date ) at each run and messes up the average calculation. If I remove the partition by the table will get ordered by EventTime(date) correctly...but I have 6 kinds of Symbols I would like the average of. What am I doing wrong?

```
select ClosePrice, Symbol, EventTime, AVG(ClosePrice) over(
partition by Symbol
order by EventTime
ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) [SMA]
from ClosePrices
```

Comment: "Rearranges my table"? Do you mean the output of that query doesn't return in a predictable order? If you want that, _add an explicit ORDER BY_.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I meant that way, thanks... question has been updated. Did you mean just specify if its ASC or DESC?

Comment: No I meant you need an ORDER BY at all. The one inside the OVER() clause doesn’t count, like Joel explained below. Think about it another way, if you had two or more OVER() clauses each with a different ORDER BY, what order would you expect the results to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is missing an `ORDER BY` clause for the final results. The `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER()` expression only applies to that window.

The SQL language is based on relational set theory concepts, which **explicitly deny** any built-in order for tables. That is, there is no guaranteed order for your tables or queries unless you deliberately set one via an `ORDER BY` clause.

In the past it may have seemed like you always get rows back in a certain order, but if so it's because *you've been lucky*. There are lots of things that can cause a database to return results in a different order, *sometimes even for different runs of the same query.*

If you care about the order of the results, you **MUST** use `ORDER BY`:

```
select ClosePrice, Symbol, EventTime, AVG(ClosePrice) over(
partition by Symbol
order by EventTime
ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) [SMA]
from ClosePrices
ORDER BY EventTime
```

Comment: Thank You much man!